# how to use HTML to PDF Library

Tags: php, html, pdf

Can anyone help me with resources on how to use HTML2PDF am a beginner, i just downloaded the library but not sure how to proceed can anyone helpout.

Thanks

Comment: Read the documentation.

Comment: google your question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know HTML2pdf, but I recommend using tcpdf. Extract the files to your server and just work of one of the examples. Very easy.